# 3x3 matrices examples to meet properties

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples

I need to find 3x3 matrices that meet the following:

a) AB not equal to BA
b) AB=BA but A not equal to B
c)AB=AC but B does not equal C
d) AB is the zero matrix but A nor B is the zero matrix

None can be the identity or zero matrix.

I've been playing with the hint etc but still struggling.  I must not be doing something right, help!  I'm not getting something, not sure what.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Because being lazy is an art-form, the simplest examples I can think of:

a)$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$. $B = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0}$

b) $A$ as above and $B = 2A$

c) $A$ as above.  $B = 2A$ and $C = 3A$.

d) $A$ as above and $B = A$.

Comment: Lazy = clean and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Just generate two random matrices and check whether $AB=BA$ is true (if it is, start again).  It unlikely to happen by chance.
2. Take one of them as $2$ times the identity matrix.
3. Try $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
4. Try $BC$ above.

Comment: note that OP has requested $3 \times 3$ examples

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Easily fixed by extending with a diagonal $1$.

Comment: Oops.  I'll fix that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a)

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$A\cdot B =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 30 & 36 & 42 \\
 54 & 66 & 78 \\
 78 & 96 & 114 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$B\cdot A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 22 & 28 & 34 \\
 49 & 64 & 79 \\
 76 & 100 & 124 \\
\end{array}
\right)$